# get all mlm downlines of an upline (php)

Tags: php, mysql, binary-tree, mlm

I want to get all down-lines of a father in a binary tree, each father has left and right arms, each arm has left and right arms etc..
[like the following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BiWb.png).
In my database i have a table called users, each user has a father id and position which is L or R.

Here is my function .. but it still don't get all downlines.
[like the following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcWkp.png).

Comment: This sounds like a pretty standard algorithmic problem. What can we help you with?

Comment: @Halcyon i need a php script to get all downlines of a father id

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coder-for-rent site. If you have a specific question we can answer it.

Comment: @Halcyon stackoverflow is to help eachother, if you want to help just do, otherwise leave the question for others to help.. i just need to compare my code with others ideas.

Comment: Then post your code.

Comment: look for recursive CTE

Comment: @Halcyon i will edit the question and add it

Comment: I just noticed that I forgot to address _"but it still don't get all downlines"_. Maybe you've already found the bug yourself but it has to do with the `$i` variable. `$i` should be unique but as you recurse down the tree values of `$i` are reused so you end up overwriting some of your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things stand out to me:

1. The `$i` argument and the use of `$this->downline_id_arr`.

Consider doing:

```
$children = array();
foreach($data as $row) {
    $child_id = $row->id;
    $children[$child_id] = array(/**/);
    $children = array_merge($children, $this->getAllDownline($child_id);
}
return $childen;
```

Now you don't need the `$i` variable or `$this->downline_id_arr`.

2. You're querying each node one by one.

Consider querying by level instead:

```
function getAllDownlines($fathers) {
    $data = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE father_id IN (/*fathers*/)";
    $new_father_ids = array();
    $children = array();
    foreach ($data as $child) {
        $children[$child->id] = array(/**/); // etc

        $new_father_ids[] = $child->id;
    }
    $children = array_merge($children, $this->getAllDownlines($new_father_ids);
    return $childen;
}
```

Typically less queries is faster so you should see better performance.